# If there is more than a page full of info then width increases

Tags: html, css

The body increases width if i have enough text on the page to fill the screen

Why does this happen?

See example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dktzLqfm/2/

```
uncomment text and see the nav bar move slightly
```

Comment: you are adding break lines to the html page. <br/> tags create line spaces in html page which creates a scroll bar so that user can scroll. I am not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Sameer wrote the question badly, should be clearer now sorry

Comment: Inline elements fill the block elements that contain them. When you insert a <br> you are forcing a line break between inline elements. You only want to do this when you have some text needs to be forced to split on two lines. For example:

    Burger
    King

In general you should only use <br> for this purpose. Instead, if you have blocks of text wrap them in the <p> (when they are paragraphs) or other appropriate block level tags. In this way they will always fill their container and the text will wrap naturally. 

Use CSS styles to set the width of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements fill the block elements that contain them. When you insert a 
 you are forcing a line break between inline elements. You only want to do this when you have some text needs to be forced to split on two lines. For example:

```
Burger
King
```

In general you should only use 
 for this purpose. Instead, if you have blocks of text wrap them in the

(when they are paragraphs) or other appropriate block level tags. In this way they will always fill their container and the text will wrap naturally.

Use CSS styles to set the width of the container.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your method but I get the same result. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/dktzLqfm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Forcing

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

on Body causes scrollbar to always show, which means the width is consistant across pages